# SQL IN "Too many values"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem I want to get all of the **DISTINCT CLIENTID**s in my LCMINV table in which the **CLIENTID** is in **LAAPPL's CLIENTID** and **LACOBORW's COBORWID** and also the **APPLICATION STATUS** is either **'PEN'** OR **'REC'**.

Here is my table:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   LAAPPL     +  LACOBORW   +  LCMINV     +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   CLIENTID   +   APPLNO    +  CLIENTID   +
+   APPLNO     +   COBORWID  +             +
+   STATUS     +             +             +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Here is my SQL Query I've done so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CLIENTID) 
FROM LCMINV 
WHERE CLIENTID 
IN (SELECT CLIENTID, COBORWID 
FROM LAAPPL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LACOBORW ON LACOBORW.APPLNO = LAAPPL.APPLNO 
WHERE STATUS = 'PEN' OR STATUS = 'REC')
```

Can it be done in one query or do I need separate queries? I tried my query above an I am getting an error **"Too many values"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use a CTE to break the query up into smaller parts, and then use `INNER JOINs` to combine the tables. Since You query `LAAPPL`, I put both columns used into a single subquery, and then join on each column in the next CTE.

It would look something like this:

```
WITH CTE_LAAPPL AS
(
    SELECT 
        CLIENTID
        ,APPLNO
    FROM LAAPPL
    WHERE STATUS IN ('PEN','REC')
)
,CLIENTIDs AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        l.COBORWID AS CLIENTID
    FROM CTE_LAAPPL c
    INNER JOIN LACOBORW l ON l.APPLNO = c.APPLNO

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT
        l.CLIENTID
    FROM CTE_LAAPPL c
    INNER JOIN LCMINV l ON l.CLIENTID = c.CLIENTID    
)
SELECT 
    c.CLIENTID
    ,c.NAME
FROM LCCLIENT c
INNER JOIN CLIENTIDs i ON i.CLIENTID = c.CLIENTID
ORDER BY NAME
```

Comment: I run you code again I added some indexes to improve searching speed and it worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.CLIENTID 
FROM LCMINV i
WHERE i.CLIENTID IN (SELECT a.CLIENTID 
                     FROM LAAPPL a JOIN 
                          LACOBORW c
                          ON c.APPLNO = a.APPLNO 
                     WHERE a.STATUS IN ('PEN', 'REC')
                    );
```

I'm not really sure why you are joining in `LACOBORW`.  You can probably remove that logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend left joins to get the data you need.  Unfortunately, your question 3 does not seem to fit your model because your **LCMINV** table does not seem to have an id that matches to another table and I cannot understand where **LCMINV.CLIENTID** should be related to in another context.  This works in MSSQL - cannot be sure about Oracle.

```
--this statement will give you all the names that have a status in the where clause
--you will receive NULL if there is no Co-BorrowerID
select
    a.name
  , b.applno
  , b.status
  , c.coborwid  
from
  lcclient a left join
  laapl b    on a.clientid = b.clientid left join
  lacoborw c on b.applno   = c.applno   
where 
  b.status in ('PEN', 'REC')
order by
  a.name
```

Comment: The results are good however I wanted to get a distinct id's only

Comment: change the __select__ to __select distinct__